# Sketchfab addon tab disappeared (& another related problem)

Tags: add-on

I have a quick question. I’ve recently started using the Sketchfab addon in Blender, and suddenly yesterday, in the Blender file in which I’ve been using it, the Sketchfab addon tab is gone from that place on the side of the viewport where you can click tabs to open panels like Item, Tool, View, and addons. Up until now it’s been there. Does anyone know what the deal might be, and how to get my Sketchfab addon tab back on the side of the viewport there? My models imported using the Sketchfab addon are still in the file I’ve been using all along, so I don’t know what’s going on. Side note, this screenshot is just one I grabbed off Google images - it’s not my interface specifically - it’s just to show the area I’m referring to where those tabs are.

As a side note, today the tab seems to be back, but everything is now greyed out or "ghosted" or whatever the term is - so it's now there again but it's seemingly useless? If anyone has any suggestions why all this is happening and how to fix it, it would be much appreciated - Thanks[image]

Comment: If it was previously working and suddenly stopped this could be due to server connection issue or login issue. As this is is Sketchfab add-on it is not a bad idea contacting their support services. Also check for new version of the add-on.

Comment: Thanks so much! I appreciate the guidance 